# Fit data with 2-tissue 3-compartments model by lmfit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm trying to fit my experimental data with a very well-known model in pharmacokinetics. The system of equations is quite complicated:

```
dC1/dt = k1*Cp - (k2+k3)*C1 + k4*C2
dC2/dt = k3*C1 - k4*C2
Ctissue = (1-vB)*(C1 + C2) + vB*Cp
```

vB is a constant, Cp is an array (dependent variable already known by measuring), k1, k2, k3, k4 are the kinetic constants between different compartments and are the parameters I would like to have from the fit. Ctissue is what I want to fit with real data. C1 and C2 are two arrays that I should be able to calculate after performing the fit. There is a commercial software (PKIN) that can calculate this system of equations so I'm sure that it's possible but I have no idea how I can implement it with python.

Here is my code

```
tini = np.array([  15.,   45.,   75.,  120.,  180.,  240.,  300.,  360.,  450.,
        570.,  690.,  810.,  930., 1080., 1260., 1440., 1650., 1890.,
       2130., 2400., 2700., 3000., 3300., 3525.])

Ctissue = np.array([  1.00229754,  25.06505484,  60.0265695 ,  82.87576127,
        68.07901198,  67.10795788,  81.42071546,  81.05644343,
       100.6740041 ,  90.43091176, 111.7861611 , 110.3851624 ,
       116.4682562 , 126.7390119 , 133.8460856 , 132.8657165 ,
       145.3951029 , 141.4012821 , 156.7317122 , 159.8293774 ,
       163.609847  , 175.7823822 , 168.5340708 , 171.5013387 ])

Cp = np.array([ 13.99461153, 559.5563251 , 914.7457277 , 782.4498718 ,
       574.7527458 , 521.4668956 , 412.9772775 , 421.5475443 ,
       403.2700613 , 368.6237412 , 355.8405377 , 340.0395723 ,
       306.9848032 , 295.0192494 , 295.0294368 , 240.9861338 ,
       245.9420067 , 217.3042524 , 229.6231028 , 196.4563327 ,
       190.8358096 , 190.161142  , 182.2021123 , 169.1384708 ])

vB = 0.05

# initial conditions
x10 = 0.1
x20 = 0.1
y0 = [x10, x20]
guess = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]

import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math as m
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def myCp( t ):
    cp = interp1d( tini, Cp )
    if np.all(t < tini[0]):  
        out = Cp[0] 
    elif np.all(t > tini[-1]):
        out = 0 
    else:
        out = cp( t )
    return out

def f(y, t, paras):
#define differential equations
    x1 = y[0]
    x2 = y[1]

    try:
        k1 = paras['k1'].value
        k2 = paras['k2'].value
        k3 = paras['k3'].value 
        k4 = paras['k4'].value

    except KeyError:
        k1, k2, k3, k4 = paras
    f1 = k1*myCp( t ) - (k2+k3)*x1 + k4*x2
    f2 = k3*x1 - k4*x2
    return [f1, f2]

def g(t, x0, paras):
    x = odeint(f, x0, t, args=(paras,))
    return x

def tis2comp3(t, paras):
    x0 = params['x10'].value, params['x20'].value
    model = g(t, x0, paras)
    x1_model = model[:, 0]
    x2_model = model[:, 1]
    Ct = (1-vB)*(x1_model + x2_model) + vB*myCp( t )
    return Ct

def residual(paras, t, data):
    Ct = tis2comp3(t, params)
    return (Ct - data).ravel()

# set parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('x10', value=x10, vary=False)
params.add('x20', value=x20, vary=False)
params.add('k1', value=guess[0], min=0.0001, max=2.)
params.add('k2', value=guess[1], min=0.0001, max=2.)
params.add('k3', value=guess[2], min=0.0001, max=2.)
params.add('k4', value=guess[3], min=0.0001, max=2.)

# fit model
result = minimize(residual, params, args=(tini, Ctissue), method='leastsq')  # leastsq nelder
# check results of the fit
xfit = np.linspace(15., 3525., 100)
yfit = tis2comp3(xfit, result.params)

#plot the final optimization results
figopt = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
lineini, = plt.plot(tini,Ctissue, 'b', linestyle='none', marker='o', markersize=7, label='data')
lineopt, = plt.plot(xfit,yfit, 'r-', label='optimized curve')
plt.legend(handles=[lineini,lineopt])
```

The fit was run smoothly but the fitted curve is unsatisfied.
Do you guys have other comments, suggestions ?

Comment: You need to tell people here which line throws the error, otherwise one will have to figure out where the error is coming from. That is too much work.

Comment: You need to "import numpy as np", this is causing the posted code to fail. I also get the error "'time' is not defined"

Comment: Please post the actual code you ran (as @Bazinga and @James Phillips point out) and also include the *complete* error message, including traceback.  This will tell you where the error occurs.   But also: check whether `x0` in `tis2comp3` should be an ndarray instead of a tuple....

Comment: thanks! I'll update my post as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi everyone! I have modified it to make my question more complete. Please take a look again when you guys have time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Newville! But how can I change it if it's the case ?

Comment: Ok, here is the problem: Every post here also is for others to look up solutions if they run into similar issues. So removing the problem from the OP and ask for the next issue in line is not how it is supposed to work. You should undo that edit and may accept the answer that actually solved this as correct (otherwise that answer solves a problem that nobody can see). The `IndexError` (next in line) we can forget about. The problem of unsatisfying results should be a new question in a separate post. I will be happy to look into it after the changes. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you mix a discrete picture using `Cp` with a quasi continuous one, using `odeint` and `f` if you look at the first output of `f` in your fitting iterations you'll see that the first, ie `f1`, is an array while the second is a number. So there is a conceptual error.

Changing your `f` to something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


tini = np.array([  
        15.,   45.,   75.,  120.,  180.,  240.,  300.,  360.,  450.,
        570.,  690.,  810.,  930., 1080., 1260., 1440., 1650., 1890.,
       2130., 2400., 2700., 3000., 3300., 3525.])

Ctissue = np.array([  
        1.00229754,   25.06505484,  60.0265695 ,  82.87576127,
        68.07901198,  67.10795788,  81.42071546,  81.05644343,
       100.6740041,   90.43091176, 111.7861611 , 110.3851624 ,
       116.4682562,  126.7390119,  133.8460856 , 132.8657165 ,
       145.3951029,  141.4012821,  156.7317122 , 159.8293774 ,
       163.609847,   175.7823822,  168.5340708 , 171.5013387 ])

Cp = np.array([ 
        13.99461153, 559.5563251 , 914.7457277 , 782.4498718 ,
       574.7527458 , 521.4668956 , 412.9772775 , 421.5475443 ,
       403.2700613 , 368.6237412 , 355.8405377 , 340.0395723 ,
       306.9848032 , 295.0192494 , 295.0294368 , 240.9861338 ,
       245.9420067 , 217.3042524 , 229.6231028 , 196.4563327 ,
       190.8358096 , 190.161142  , 182.2021123 , 169.1384708 ])

vB = 0.05

def myCp( t ):
    cp = interp1d( tini, Cp )
    if t < tini[0]: # does this makes sense 
        out = Cp[0] # may require to be refined
    elif t > tini[-1]:
        out = Cp[-1] # same here.
    else:
        out = cp( t )
    return out

def f( y, t, paras ):
#define differential equations
    x1 = y[0]
    x2 = y[1]
    k1, k2, k3, k4 = paras
    f1 = k1 * myCp( t ) - ( k2 + k3 ) * x1 + k4 * x2
    f2 = k3 * x1 - k4 * x2
    return [ f1, f2 ]
paras=[.1, .12, .14, .15 ]
sol = odeint( f, [ .1, .2], tini, args=( paras, ) )

print sol[ :, 0 ]
print sol[ :, 1 ]
```

should work.

As `odeint` checks values beyond the `t` limits, you have to figure out what a reasonable extrapolation would look like.

Comment: I agree - the problem seems to be in the framing of the derivative function `f` for `odeint`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your suggestions and modify f like this

Comment: @vulong is your new error just a simple index error. `g` has two solutions so it should be `model[ :, 0 ]` and `model[ :, 1 ]`, like in the last two lines of my code.

Comment: @mikuszefski thanks, I modified everything and put it in the question. The fit was done but not like what I expected as you can see from the graph. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @vulong What does unsatisfying mean? Do you have an idea how `C1` and `C2` should more or less look like? That might allow for some reasonable simulation with expected outcome. Considering the evolution of `Cp` the extrapolation to `Cp=0` for larger times seems quite harsh.

Comment: Great idea. I'll make a fit by PKIN and show you guys the results. It should give you an idea. I'll do it whenever I have time. You're right maybe Cp won't drop to 0 that fast. Thank you!

Comment: @vulong Is there a closed  form for `Cp`. It looks like a power law decay, but a steep rise in the beginning. Any idea about the theoretical shape of this?

Comment: Hi. I didn't have time to run the fit yet. Indeed, it might be exponential decay. It is the concentration of radiomarker in the blood. There are people trying to give a theoretical function for it but they are not perfect, always underestimate a bit the peak. I don't know if PKIN fit it automatically or automatically cut the rising part before putting it in the ODE system. It's possible. The way it looks doesn't seem so but it could be.

Comment: Sure, from concentration you'd expect some exponential, `loglog` plot suggests approx `t**(-1./2)`, though. Moreover, you might be right that the data up to the peak is neglected. I guess that this is from a local injection and the peak occurs after a certain time it needs to spread. As this is a different mechanism, the model might not be suitable for this part anyway.

Comment: Actually, it was IV injection. But thanks to nuclear imaging we were able to trace the activity of the molecule even before it had time to reach peak concentration in the heart where we suppose the activity would be equivalent to that of the blood. But in fact theoretically speaking, we can remove it to simplify the fit.